# The most popular travel websites in South Korea?

Tags: online-resources, south-korea

Our family runs a small restaurant in Venice, Italy. Since we think that South Korea is an interesting market, we're thinking about advertising our restaurant on a Korean website that might be read by travellers that wants to visit Italy and our city.

Do you know which travel websites are the most visited among South koreans (aside from tripadvisor)?

Comment: You could try Google AdWords for keywords related to Venice restaurants (or Korean-language keywords linking to a Korean-language version of your website) targeting South Korean users.

Comment: What kind of travel websites are you looking for? Booking flights? Hotel reservations?

Comment: I was actually thinking about a korean travel website or a travel blog that might list places where a tourist could stop and have a lunch or a dinner... something like Yelp or Tripadvisor. It's ok if the site is less popular, because almost every restaurant, bar or pizzeria is already reachable on tripadvisor everywhere in the world, while a less-known website might bring us potentially less visitors but since we'd have less competition we would have bigger chances to appear in the first results on a search for restaurants in Venice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by contacting the Italian Tourism department to see if they target the Korean travel market, as they would likely have done research on the best marketing venues.  You could also try contacting some neighboring tourism departments as other EU members might target Korean travelers.

Do some web searches for travel magazines in Korean language.  http://www.w3newspapers.com/south-korea/magazines/ lists a number of travel periodicals.

And of course, the biggest marketing question of all ... What makes your restaurant attractive to Korean travelers?  (ie: why do you feel Korea is a good market for you)

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. Unfortunately the Italian Tourism department (E.N.I.T.) simply doesn't work as it should and each italian district has its own tourism department that advertise their own companies. Pretty strange, uh? :-) In our case, my district of competence would be "Veneto", but I'm not very sure that they'd know how to help me on this topic. I'm feeling that the south korean tourists are increasing a lot in these latest years, and I was thinking "hey, maybe if I am one of the first to advertise myself in that country I could get some attention."